# Gummi won't compile document after compiling bibliography, table error

Tags: tables, bibliographies, errors, compiling

I'm new to this whole LaTeX thing, and I'm having a problem that I can't even begin to understand. I've written a great big document with several tables and images, and previously everything worked fine - Gummi compiled the document live, and I could export as PDF whenever I liked.

I've now gone and attached a .bib file with the naive intention of simply adding a bibliography to my dissertation. There's 62 references, and none of them are cited in the main text (I'd already done this manually and used \nocite{*} instead).

Anyway, I'm on the Bibliography tab and I can detect and compile the bibliography no trouble. But now when I click back on the main Preview Pane, the document won't compile and it seems to highlight an error with one of my tables that previously worked absolutely fine. If I remove the table, it just finds an error with the next one. It makes no sense, my deadline is in less than 36 hours, and frankly I'm wishing I'd stuck to Microsoft Word right now.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this???

Comment: UPDATE: problem solved! I trawled through the build log, and saw something about a misplaced alignment character... a bit of Googling and messing about with my .bib file, and then I realised that RefWorks had included a load of & symbols in the .bib file, which LaTeX was taking exception to. Swapped 'em all out for \& instead, recompiled and there it was, all working again.

Seriously though, there must be a more idiot-proof way of avoiding this sort of thing? It amazes me that this problem was even able to happen at all. Anyway, enough rambling. I need some sleep. Or coffee...

Comment: That behaviour is very well documented as `&` is needed in tables. Never trust auto-generated bibliography items.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments by op.